# Mac OS X Mavericks virtual keyboard

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, keyboard-layout, osx-mavericks, virtual-keyboard

I am looking for a way to get OS X Mountain Lion or Mavericks virtual keyboard to display without the number pad. I only want the main keyboard without the numbers on the side of the screen. I have used Ukulele Keyboard Layout Editor to create my keyboard layout, but that's no use. The custom keyboard uses the Mac default keyboard layout.

I also was able to set the keyboard type to ISO instead of ANSI and it worked, but when I launch the virtual keyboard it displays as ANSI and I have to press the <kbd>A</kbd> key on the physical keyboard to switch to the ISO keyboard.

Is there a way that I can make the virtual keyboard set to ISO European type of keyboard without pressing any keys on the physical keyboard? I am simply looking for a way to get the virtual keyboard to display with no numbers.